# How do I change solely the latin math alphabet?

Tags: beamer, math-fonts

I am using the Eb Garamond font in a Beamer presentation, but I want to switch the math font to regular Computer Modern (the numerals in Garamond are sometimes strange).

In the past, I have used a code similar to this:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldmath}{OML}{cmm}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldmath}
```

However, in this document, this only changes the Greek letters, and leaves the Latin letters and numerals unchanged.

What should I do?

See a test file bellow:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{serif}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}

\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldmath}{OML}{cmm}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathnormal}{letters}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldmath}
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Model Environment}

\[u_P(d_p) =  [r+ \beta(d_P - 1/2)] +  \alpha d_P\]
        
\end{frame}
   
\end{document}
```

Comment: What compiler (engine) are you using? That might make a difference.

Comment: I am using overleaf

Comment: I meant: pdflatex, laualtex, xelatex, etc. Unless Overleaf beamer forces a particular method

Comment: Oh, I am using pdflatex

Comment: Do you want the math to be serif or sans serif? Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: As the name suggests, `ebgaramond-maths` changes maths. If you don't want that, there's zero reason to load it. All it does apart from loading `ebgaramond` is change maths stuff. So `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`. (And the `professionalfonts` stuff from the answer below so it is actually effective.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- beamer normally uses letters etc. from the normal text font in math mode (there are not a lot of sans serif math fonts available, so this a quick way to get math symbols for the normally sans serif font of beamer). To switch this off, you can use the `professionalfonts` font theme.
- to only change the text to EB Garamond and not the math fonts, try the `ebgaramond` package instead of `ebgaramond-maths`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{serif}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
%
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Model Environment}

abc xyz

\[abc xyz u_P(d_p) =  [r+ \beta(d_P - 1/2)] +  \alpha d_P\]
        
\end{frame}
   
\end{document}
```

[image]